# Counterexamples between Rings and their polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I have seen that if you have a ring $R$ which is also a field $F$ then its corresponding polynomial ring $R[x]$ is an Euclidean domain.

So I am looking for counter examples of the converse that when $R[x]$ is an Euclidean domain then R need not be a field. I am not really sure how to look for these examples. Maybe there is some trivial ones that I have overlooked? or some non trivial examples ?

Comment: It is in fact true that $R[x]$ is a principal ideal domain if and only if $R$ is a field (and thus if and only if $R[x]$ is an Euclidean domain). See  [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_Forms_is_PID_Implies_Coefficient_Ring_is_Field). It has already been asked here as well, but I'm still loking for an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: thanks I see now